# How long should a good synposis be for a novel?

Tags: fiction, novel, plot, book-length, synopsis

I have always been poor at writing things without including excessive detail, but I managed to rewrite my synopsis with very little detail and with personal detailed side notes not included within the actual synopsis. It is solely the overall plot, but it is still 18 pages. Is this too long?

Comment: [somebody answered this question before here](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/40/how-do-i-write-a-synopsis)

Comment: The proposed duplicate is for general advice about synopsis-writing; this one is specifically about length.

Answer (score 4):

Quote from the linked source, which pretty much summarizes the article:

> ...if you ever send me five page synopsis for every 15K words I'll toss it unread. 3-5 is the MAX no matter how long your novel is. And no cheating by using 5pt fonts and .25 inch margins. Synopsis are not a blow for blow recitation of the plot. It's major points, turning points, character description and development and it's SHORT...

["Miss Snark, the literary agent", answers the question about the preferred length of the synopsis of a novel in her blog post.](http://misssnark.blogspot.com/2005/10/synopsis-flopsis.html)

Comment: Could you briefly summarize the content of the page you linked to? This will help future visitors to the site in case of link rot.

Comment: Unexplained links and one sentence answers are a faux pas.  Please make this answer more substantial or I will downvote it.  Links should be used to reference what is being explained.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum: added a synopsis to the link...

Comment: no, you *described* what was in the link. Please *recap* what's in the link. "Miss Snark says blah blah blah because XYZ, and TKTKTK because of her experience in such-and-such." The link above would still be useless if the source page went away, which is what "link rot" means.